# Google is showing my site in the search results with dashes in the www subdomain

Tags: seo, google-search

I'm experience something I find weird. On google searches, my links are alright but for some reason some of them are showing like this:

- `w-ww.example.com`
- `www-.example.com`

Comment: What happens when you click on that?  Does your site still work?   Does the `w-ww` show in the browser URL bar?

Comment: the website still works, but for some reason the results come up with http://w-ww. instead the normal www., i wonder if im doing something wrong or already happen with someone, or is it just a "google thing"

Comment: I'm sure there is something you can do to fix it, this doesn't happen for most websites.    When you say the website "works", does it show `w-ww` in the browser URL bar?

Comment: What are your DNS records?  Do you have a wildcard DNS?

Comment: What server and host are you using?    What virtual hosts do you have configured in the web server?

Comment: *update*, just seen the results now, yesterday i went to webmaster tools and requested the re-indexation of the link, somehow it fixed it and its showing properly again.